# Selectively merge changes in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, merge, branch, cvs

When updating a branch in CVS with code from the head I'm doing this with the [Update Directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/update-directory-update-file-dialog-%28cvs%29.html) dialogue.
Unfortunately all non-conflicting changes from the head are applied in this way without asking.

In [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) it is possible to selectively mark which changes and files should be merged.
Has [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) such a functionality as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no such thing as [Eclipe's Synchronize View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28720290/intellij-doesnt-recognize-import-statements-for-jaxb-classes) in IntelliJ. You've got to use the [Update Directory dialogue](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/update-directory-update-file-dialog-cvs-.html).