# IntelliJ doesn't recognize import statements for JAXB classes

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jaxb, jaxb2

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 14 as IDE and [jaxb2-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/) for creating Java classes from XSD files.

When compiling my module with Maven no errors are displayed. Even when using the command `make` or `compile` in IntelliJ no errors are displayed in the status popup.

But in the files itself and in the project browser compile errors are constantly displayed. It seems like IntelliJ doesn't recognize the import statements of my classes in the target folder.

The error statements look like this (bold means coloured in red):

*com.my.package.**generated**.MyClass*

The `generated` package seems to be invisible for the IDE. How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After using [this workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123702#comment=27-727028) and recreating my project it worked again.

Quote:

> If you use maven-jaxb2-plugin with multiple schema for example
>
> ```
>         <configuration>
>             <bindingDirectory>src/main/xjb/</bindingDirectory>
>             <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
>         </configuration>
> ```
>
> with multiple xsd/xjb in it. One with:
>
> ```
>     <jaxb:schemaBindings>
>         <jaxb:package name="com.test.a"/>
>     </jaxb:schemaBindings>
> ```
>
> Another with:
>
> ```
>     <jaxb:schemaBindings>
>         <jaxb:package name="com.test.b"/>
>     </jaxb:schemaBindings>
> ```

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).